Unsatisfied Link Error error of Java Native Interface DLL
I have a strange problem with my Java JNI windows DLL program. I can load and run immaculately on Windows 10 machine on which the DLL program was developed. It provides basic camera interfaces using Media Foundation which is win32 APIs.
When I copy to another machine (which is Windows 11), I get the unsatisfied Java module load error.  It says "Can't find dependent libraries". It works on Windows 10. Not in another machine! The following is a stack trace;
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\AnamonCamera-win64.dll10819000438203799267: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at anamon.camera.Webcam.<clinit>(Webcam.java:43)
    at anamon.cms.ImageStereoVision.run(ImageStereoVision.java:372)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The following is JNI Visual Studio C++ program snippets which shows included libraries and APIs used. It's a basic camera interface program that get a list of camera names and fetch images from a camera. It uses Media Foundation APIs which is win32 that doesn't require extra installations.
#include "jni.h"

#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")

// JNI interface functions call this;
int setupCameraDeviceList() {
    HRESULT hr;
    if (!mfinitialized) {
       hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);
       if (FAILED(hr)) {
           return -3;
       }
    }

    hr = MFCreateAttributes(&videoConfig, 1);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
       return -4;
    }

    ......
}

The following is Java DLL loading part. It extracts DLL file stored in a Jar file and store on a temp file. Then the temp file is loaded. Here I get the error;
  String dllname = "AnamonCamera-win64";
  File temp = WebcamTools.extractInJarDllFileAndCreateTempFile(dllname);
  System.load(temp.getAbsolutePath()); // Here I get the error!
  temp.delete();

The following is Visual Studion CMakeLists.txt file.
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

project ("AnamonCameraMF-win64")

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             AnamonCamera-win64

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             AnamonCameraMF.cpp
        )


I suspect this CMakeLists.txt file may need something. Otherwise it could be visual studio license, java or windows security issue. Currently I subscribed monthly Visual Studio professional. Probably not charged yet.
It could be I am making a simple mistake as I am not expert on Visual Studio matter. I use Visual Studio 2022 professional and community editions.

Does the file exist at that exact path? It is a very common error when a DLL can not be found.

Which edition of Windows is on the computer that this error occurs on? If it includes "N" or "KN", then perhaps you need to add the "Media Feature Pack" optional feature.

It's windows 11 pro. No N appended. There is no add optional feature for media feature pack.

The temp dll file does exist with the correct length.

Use dependency walker to investigate the DLL dependencies of the temp dll file. Common cause is forgetting to install (the right version of) the MSVC redistributable on the target machine

I solved this problem. I was using DEBUG version DLL. After changing to release version. It works like a charm. Thanks for helps.

The debug libraries are generally not installed on non-developer systems, so there's your explanation.

You need to stick the DLL into a dependancy walker and find out all the names of the files it loads and then make sure they are all there.  The debug MSVC runtime has a different name than the non-debug one that comes with windows...
